# Поиск часть объекта в объекте

Tags: javascript, typescript

есть два объекта:

```
const actual =  {a: 'a', b: {c: 'c'}};
const expected = {c: 'c'};
```

Нужно вывести true/false, в зависимости, находится ли expected в actual объекте.
Вложенность может быть любая как для actual, так и для expected.
В т.ч. могут быть и массивы
Использовал `deepEqual`, но он сравнивает все данные

Подскажите библиотеку, для **частичного** поиска в объекте

Comment: Можно попробовать через JSON.stringify(). Преобразовать actual и expected в строку и поискать вхождение. С массивами посложнее, надо будет как то отсортировать

Comment: применяй deepEqual для всех значений

Comment: @SwaD, почему с массивами сложнее?

Comment: @Grundy массив [1,2,3] и массив [3,1,2] это один и тот же массив? Если да, то перед преобразованием в строку, массивы надо будет отсортировать

Comment: Есть еще кейс, когда объект содержит методы, то JSON.stringify() просто удалит этот поле объекта. Не знаю насколько такой кейс применим в этом примере, но в общем случае может выстрелить. Если речь идет о тестах, то в Jest есть метод [objectContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject)

Comment: `expected` - это всегда какой-то объект? Т.е. может быть что `expected = 'c'`? Если да, то каков должен быть ответ с вашим `actual`?

Comment: @EzioMercer и там и там объект json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью lodash

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const actual = { a: "a", b: { c: { d: "d", e: "e", f: "f" } } };
const expected = { b: { c: { d: "d" } } };
const expected2 = { b: { c: { d: "d", e: "FFF" } } };

console.log(_.isMatch(actual, expected))
>>> true
console.log(_.isMatch(actual, expected2))
>>> false
```